# Why UTF-8 fail on this encoding?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

I'm about to download a [page](http://www.rollingstonemagazine.it/musica/foto-musica/sexy-covers-60-di-quei-dischi-vietati-ai-minori/?utm_content=buffer63827&utm_source=buffer&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Buffer) encoded in UTF-8.
So this is my code:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent", Request.UserAgent);

    htmlPage = client.DownloadString(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(resoruce_url));

    var KeysParsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"].Replace(" ", "").Replace(";", "&"));
    var charset = ((KeysParsed["charset"] != null) ? KeysParsed["charset"] : "UTF-8");
    Response.Write(client.ResponseHeaders);

    byte[] bytePage = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset).GetBytes(htmlPage);
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(bytePage), Encoding.GetEncoding(charset)))
    {
        htmlPage = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Response.Write(htmlPage);
    }
}
```

so, it set `UTF-8` for the encoding. But the downloaded title, for example, show in my screen as:

```
Sexy cover: 60 e piÃ¹ di “quei dischi” vietati ai minori
```

and not as:

```
Sexy cover: 60 e più di “quei dischi” vietati ai minori
```

somethings is wrong, but I don't find where. Any ideas?

Comment: What does it say if you use a web browser?

Comment: Using a web browser the correct text on the title is `Sexy cover: 60 e più di “quei dischi” vietati ai minori`. Try yourself, open it with Firefox :)

Comment: "Sexy covers". I'm at work sir. Try UTF-16 and ASCII Western European and see what it says. Are you sure you should be defaulting to UTF-8?

Comment: Also, are there any headers that may tell you what the encoding is?

Comment: `var KeysParsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"].Replace(" ", "").Replace(";", "&"));`  What is this code supposed to be doing?

Comment: `Ã + extra char` instead of a single accented Latin character is a standard pattern, caused by interpreting UTF-8 as Latin1.

Comment: @Matthew: it catch the charset of the ResponseHeader's Content-Type. It is `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`, so I parse it in this way. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that by the time you get the data it's already been converted.

When `WebClient.DownloadString` executes, it gets the raw bytes and converts them to a string using the default encoding. The damage is done. You can't take the resulting string, turn it back into bytes, and re-interpret it.

Put another way, this is what's happening:

```
// WebClient.DownloadString does, essentially, this.
byte[] rawBytes = DownloadData();
string htmlPage = Encoding.Default.GetString(rawBytes);

// Now you're doing this:
byte[] myBytes = Encoding.Utf8.GetBytes(htmlPage);
```

But `myBytes` will not necessarily be the same as `rawBytes`.

If you know what encoding to use beforehand, you can set the `WebClient` instance's `Encoding` property. If you want to interpret the string based on the encoding specified in the Content-Type header, then you have to download the raw bytes, determine the encoding, and use that to interpret the string. For example:

```
var rawBytes = client.DownloadData(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(resoruce_url));
var KeysParsed = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(client.ResponseHeaders["Content-Type"].Replace(" ", "").Replace(";", "&"));
var charset = ((KeysParsed["charset"] != null) ? KeysParsed["charset"] : "UTF-8");

var theEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(charset);
htmlPage = theEncoding.GetString(rawBytes);
```

Comment: Ah there is `GetString()`, so I don't need GetBytes at all! thank you man!